# Extend a specific version of Python (on Linux Ubuntu/Unity)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, module, mpmath

I recently got Ubuntu 11.10 and put several versions of Python on it,
including EPD Python, Python 2.7 (standard) and Python 3.2.
I'm primarily using the EPD distribution and wanted to extend it with
the mpmath module. Basically that sounds very easy but Linux always 
installs the package to the standard 2.7 or 3.2 version.

How can I specifically extend the EPD　distribution? I must confess that I'm pretty new to both Linux and Python, so there is hopefully an easy solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're installing the package with easy_install, you can do

```
 python_executable_name -m easy_install packagename
```

That will install the package to that python version.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! part of the problem was that they called themselves the same (both python2.7). Maybe this could also be solved this way. I now installed the package into the pythonpath of my favorit distribution (manually) and it worked.